# Laravel belongsToMany with OR condition

Tags: php, mysql, laravel

How do I create brackets around my orWhere:

```
public function categories()
{
    return $this->belongsToMany('App\Category', 'user_category')->orWhere('default', 1);
}
```

So it is converted to this:

```
where (`user_category`.`user_id` = ? or `default` = 1)
```

Currently the brackets here are missing and mess up the whole query. I tried for example:

```
public function categories()
{
    $join = $this->belongsToMany('App\Category', 'user_category')
      ->orWhere('default', 1);
    return $this->where(function ($query) use ($join) {
        return $join;
    });
}
```

But here I am loosing my model and getting `Call to undefined method Illuminate\Database\Query\Builder::...`

Answer (score 0):

You can use [advanced where clause](https://laravel.com/docs/4.2/queries#advanced-wheres) like:

```
Model::where(function ($query) {
    $query->where('a', '=', 1)
          ->orWhere('b', '=', 1);
})->where(function ($query) {
    $query->where('c', '=', 1)
          ->orWhere('d', '=', 1);
});
```

Or nested clause [like](http://You%20can%20nest%20where%20clauses):

```
Model::where(function($query)
{
    $query->where('a', 'like', 'keyword');
    $query->or_where('b', 'like', 'keyword');
})
->where('c', '=', '1');
```

Comment: That's what I have tried. But how does this work with `belongsToMany`? $query->belongsToMany() does not work inside this function. That's why I tried to get it inside with `use ($join)` but that still does not work.

Answer (score 0):

Are you trying to get all the categories related to an user and the categories where the `default` field is 1?

If that is the case:

```
public function categories()
{
    return $this->belongsToMany('App\Category');
}

public function relatedCategories()
{
    return App\Category::all()->where('default',1)->merge($this->categories);
}
```

The `relatedCategories()` method should return a collection with the desired categories. Take in care that the non-related categories but with `default=1` will not have the `pivot` object, because these categories doesn't exist in your pivot table.

Comment: Right, that looks nice, but still it returns the category model. `categories()` returns the BelongsToMany object with the user model as parent, so you can still call query scopes methodes from the user.